# Definite article alongside "use"

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

I've got these two examples:

> However, **use** of these drugs is discouraged by pregnant women or women trying to conceive and should be thoroughly discussed with your health care provider and dermatologist.

https://americanpregnancy.org/pregnancy-health/acne-during-pregnancy/

> **The use** of safety belts is mandatory.

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34714/43581

Are both correct? Is there a reason why the definite article is used or not in these cases?

Comment: Both are normal usage. Why do you think they aren't?

Comment: @MikeBrockington I don't think. I'm just trying to understand when to use the definite article :) Is there any difference that using or not using it here makes?

Comment: The definite article is optional in both examples; different settings may prefer one or the other.